# LINQ Query Help

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have this query which runs a join on Books, TradingDesks and ProductInfos. The data is huge in each of this collection.

```
var queryJoin = from b in books.Values
                                    join d in tradingDesks.Values
                                        on b.TradingDeskId equals d.Id
                                    join p in ProductInfos.Values
                                        **on b.Id equals p.RiskBookId** 
                                    select new { p, Book = b.Name, TradingDeskName = d.Name };
```

In the highlighted line `(on b.Id equals p.RiskBookId)`, I also want to add another condition like, `(on b.Id equals p.RiskBookId || p.RiskBookId == 0)` . How do I do this in this linq syntax.

I tried querying like this

```
var queryJoin = from b in books.Values
                from d in tradingDesks.Values.Where(x => x.Id == b.TradingDeskId)
                from p in cachedProductInfos.Values.Where(y => y.RiskBookId == b.Id)
                select new { p, Book = b.Name, TradingDeskName = d.Name };
```

But in this case, the query runs forever and I run out of memory. So I guess framing it in this fashion does something crazy :(

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Mani

Comment: This seems to be completely linq-to-objects, I don't see where the linq-to-sql fits in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original query, those calls to Enumerable.Join are using a hashtable behind the scenes to make things fast.  If you switch to .Where, you don't get those hash benefits.  You can use hashing explicitly to get the same effect.

```
ILookup<int, string> deskNameLookup = tradingDesks.Values
  .ToLookup(
    d => d.Id,
    d => d.Name
  );

ILookup<int, ProductInfo> infoLookup = ProductInfos.Values
  .ToLookup(p.RiskBookId);

foreach(b in books.Values)
{
  foreach(dName in deskNameLookup[b.TradingDeskId])
  {
    foreach(p in infoLookup[b.Id].Concat(infoLookup[0]))
    {
      var x = new {p, Book = b.Name, TradingDeskName = dName};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. This looks more promising. But I am stuck up to use this option since I have this query expression as IQuerayble and do further more operations on this. Any idea on how I can load this in to an IQueryable ?

Comment: Marking this as answer though this is something not solving the issue. This explains why my query takes a longer time than normal.

Answer (score 1):

you could try framing it as a union instead of a single join:

```
var baseQuery = 
    from book in books.Values
    join desk in tradingDesks.Values on book.TradingDeskId equals desk.Id
    select new {book, desk};

var conditionOne = 
    from baseQ in baseQuery
    join productInfo in ProductInfos.Values on baseQ.book.Id equals productInfo.RiskBookId
    select new 
    { 
        productInfo, 
        Book = baseQ.book.Name, 
        TradingDeskName = baseQ.desk.Name
    };

var conditionTwo = 
    from baseQ in baseQuery
    join productInfo in ProductInfos.Values on book.Id equals 0
    select new 
    {
        productInfo, 
        Book = baseQ.book.Name, 
        TradingDeskName = baseQ.desk.Name
    };

var result = conditionOne.Union(conditionTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

`equals` can only be used to do a single comparison.

Someone else may be able to give you an optimised approach to the query for your circumstance, but adding to the `equals` condition isn't the solution here. What might be best though is to approach it in a different fashion - rather than yanking at all the data from within the body of a single query - by some sort of bespoke loading and caching mechanism, since the size of the data is obviously problematic.

Answer (score 0):

try this, a little verbatim but should work as you described it:

```
var queryJoin =
    from b in books.Values
    join d in tradingDesks.Values on b.TradingDeskId equals d.Id
    let p =
        from pi in ProductInfos.Values
        where (b.Id == pi.RiskBookId) || (pi.RiskBookId == 0)
        select pi
    where p.Any()
    select new
    {
        p,
        Book = b.Name,
        TradingDeskName = d.Name
    };
```

Comment: the problem might be `(pi.RiskBookId == 0)` which depends on your data if you have large amount of records with that condition

Comment: You are right. Thinking of it from another angle, all I need is like a outer join on the ProductInfo collection. Still working on the same one, no solution yet ....

Answer (score -1):

Actually :

```
join d in tradingDesks.Values
    on (b.Id equals p.RiskBookId || p.RiskBookId equals 0)
```

or

```
on (b.Id == p.RiskBookId || p.RiskBookId == 0)
```

Should work perfectly fine.

The join requires a true condition:

```
on <expression>

(b.Id equals p.RiskBookId || p.RiskBookId == 0)
```

will return true or false, so the join SHOULD evaluate that just so.

Comment: This does not compile !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!var queryJoin = from b in books.Values
                join d in tradingDesks.Values
                on b.TradingDeskId equals d.Id
                join p in cachedProductInfos.Values
            on (b.Id  equals p.RiskBookId || p.RiskBookId equals 0)
         select new { p, Book = b.Name, TradingDeskName = d.Name };

Comment: Ah well - so much for Linq being that similar to SQL. :)