# LINQ to SQL Help

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have this query which runs a join on Books, TradingDesks and ProductInfos.

```
var queryjoin = from b in books.values
                join d in tradingdesks
                    on b.tradingdeskid equals d.id
                **join p in productinfoss**
                    on b.id equals p.riskbookid
                select new { p, book = b.name, tradingdeskname = d.name };
```

In the last join, ***I would like to do an right outer join with the Products***. I am trying not to use dynamic sql query and trying to get this work with linq itself. I dont want to use where since this greatly affects performance. I tried linq to objects earlier but couldnt get right performance and now trying linq to sql but still cant get this through. [LINQ Query Help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6439548/448314) . Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (check for typo of `productinfos(s)`):

EDIT: Sorry, I gave you the left outer join. Right outer join is not available in Linq, so you need to reformat the query slightly.

```
var queryjoin = from p in productinfos
                join b in books.values
                    on p.riskbookid equals b.id into outer
                from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join d in tradingdesks
                    on o.tradingdeskid equals d.id
                select new { 
                       p,
                       book = (o==null) ? "(no book name)" : o.name,
                       tradingdeskname = d.name 
                       };
```

Comment: Isnt this the left outer join equivalent ?

Comment: Yes, sorry you're right! It needs to be reordered into a left outer join (or you can use groups). Hang on...

Answer (score 1):

please try the following

```
var queryjoin = from p in productinfoss
                join b in books.values on p.riskbookid equals b.id into temp
                from t in temp.DefaultIFEmpty()
                join d in tradingdesks on 
                t.tradingdeskid equals d.id
                new { p, book = t==null?"no name":t.name, tradingdeskname = d.name };
```

it should work in this scenario. i have not tested it though

Comment: no. this doesnt produce the expected result. In my intial query, I would get all the products

Comment: that's what you will get by taking right outer join on products. what else you want this query to return you

Comment: ---Yours-----
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[Family]
FROM [EVF_TradeService].[dbo].[Product] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [EVF_HierarchyService].[dbo].[Book] AS [t1] ON [t0].[RiskBookId] = [t1].[Id]
INNER JOIN [EVF_HierarchyService].[dbo].[TradingDesk] AS [t2] ON [t1].[TradingDeskId] = [t2].[Id]
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: ---What I need----
SELECT  distinct t2.Family 
FROM [EVF_HierarchyService].[dbo].[Book] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [EVF_HierarchyService].[dbo].[TradingDesk] AS [t1] ON [t0].[TradingDeskId] = [t1].[Id]
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [EVF_TradeService].[dbo].[Product] AS [t2] ON [t0].[Id] = [t2].[RiskBookId]

Comment: These are the sqls genrated out of the linq query of yours. These both doesnt return the same result set.

Comment: well without the database it is difficult to tell what's going on